# Error when evaluating models: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and continuous targets

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm encountering an issue while trying to evaluate various regression models in Python using scikit-learn. I have implemented a code to train and evaluate different algorithms, including LinearRegression, DecisionTreeRegressor, RandomForestRegressor, SVR, and MLPRegressor. However, when attempting to calculate classification metrics such as accuracy, precision, recall, and F1-score for these regression models, I'm encountering the following error:

> ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and continuous targets

From what I understand, this error occurs because I am attempting to use classification metrics on a regression problem. However, my dataset contains only binary outcome variables, so this shouldn't be an issue.

Here's a version of my code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import sklearn.feature_selection
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor


# Find performance of model using preprocessed data
algorithms = {
    'LogisticRegression': {
        'constructor': LogisticRegression(max_iter=4),
        'predict': lambda m, x_test: m.predict(x_test),
        'predict_prob': lambda m, x_test: m.predict_proba(x_test)[::, 1],
    },
    'LinearRegression': {
        'constructor': LinearRegression(),
        'predict': lambda m, x_test: m.predict(x_test),
        'predict_prob': None,
    },
    'DecisionTreeRegressor': {
        'constructor': DecisionTreeRegressor(),
        'predict': lambda m, x_test: m.predict(x_test),
        'predict_prob': None,
    },
    'RandomForestRegressor': {
        'constructor': RandomForestRegressor(),
        'predict': lambda m, x_test: m.predict(x_test),
        'predict_prob': None,
    },
    'SVR': {
        'constructor': SVR(),
        'predict': lambda m, x_test: m.predict(x_test),
        'predict_prob': None,
    },
    'MLPRegressor': {
        'constructor': MLPRegressor(),
        'predict': lambda m, x_test: m.predict(x_test),
        'predict_prob': None,
    },
}

def ds_split(dataset, dependent_var, split):
    # Split into features and outcomes
    x = dataset.drop(dependent_var, axis=1)
    y = dataset.get(dependent_var)

    # Split data into train and test sets
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, train_size=split, random_state=1)

    # Select the best features
    select = sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest(k="all")
    selected_features = select.fit(x_train, y_train)
    indices_selected = selected_features.get_support(indices=True)
    colnames_selected = [x.columns[i] for i in indices_selected]

    x_train_selected = x_train[colnames_selected]
    x_test_selected = x_test[colnames_selected]

    # Split data into train and test sets
    return x_train_selected, x_test_selected, y_train, y_test


datasets = {
    'processed': ds_split(undersampled_df, 'hospital_expire_flag', 0.7)}

models = [
    {
        'algo': 'LogisticRegression',
        'ds': 'processed',
    },
    {
        'algo': 'LinearRegression',
        'ds': 'processed',
    },
    {
        'algo': 'DecisionTreeRegressor',
        'ds': 'processed',
    },
    {
        'algo': 'RandomForestRegressor',
        'ds': 'processed',
    },
    {
        'algo': 'SVR',
        'ds': 'processed',
    },
    {
        'algo': 'MLPRegressor',
        'ds': 'processed',
    },
]
```

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error, r2_score
import pickle # For saving the model to a file
from sklearn import metrics


def evaluate_model(algo, x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, model_filename):
    # Fit the model
    model = algo['constructor']
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)

    #Save model
    with open(model_filename, 'wb') as file:
        pickle.dump(model, file)


    # Predict Test Data
    y_pred = algo['predict'](model, x_test)

    # Calculate accuracy, precision, recall, f1-score, and kappa score
    acc = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    prec = metrics.precision_score(y_test, y_pred)
    rec = metrics.recall_score(y_test, y_pred)
    f1 = metrics.f1_score(y_test, y_pred)
    kappa = metrics.cohen_kappa_score(y_test, y_pred)
    mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
    rmse = np.sqrt(mse)
    mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)


    # Calculate area under curve (AUC)
    y_pred_proba = algo['predict_prob'](model, x_test)
    fpr, tpr, _ = metrics.roc_curve(y_test, y_pred_proba)
    auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred_proba)

    # Display confussion matrix
    cm = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

    return {'acc': acc, 'prec': prec, 'rec': rec, 'f1': f1, 'kappa': kappa,
            'fpr': fpr, 'tpr': tpr, 'auc': auc, 'cm': cm, 'mse': mse, 'rmse': rmse, 'mae': mae}


for model in models:
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = datasets[model['ds']]
    
    # Generate model filename based on algorithm
    model_name = model['algo'] 
    model_filename = f"{model_name}_model.pickle"
    model['metrics'] = evaluate_model(algorithms[model['algo']], x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test, model_filename)

    model_acc = model['metrics']['acc']
    model_prec = model['metrics']['prec']
    model_rec = model['metrics']['rec']
    model_f1 = model['metrics']['f1']
    model_kappa = model['metrics']['kappa']
    model_auc = model['metrics']['auc']
    
    print(f'Algorithm: {model_name} | accuracy: {model_acc} | precision: {model_prec} | rec: {model_rec} | f1: {model_f1} | kappa: {model_kappa} | auc: {model_auc})
```

I've checked and all features are binary:

```
binary_columns = []
solo = []
non_binary_columns = []

for col in undersampled_df.columns:
    if undersampled_df[col].nunique() == 2:
        binary_columns.append(col)
    if undersampled_df[col].nunique() == 1:
        solo.append(col)
    if undersampled_df[col].nunique() > 2:
        non_binary_columns.append(col)

print("Binary Columns:")
print(binary_columns)
print("\n Non Binary Columns:")
print(non_binary_columns)
print("\n Solo Columns:")
print(solo)
```

```
Binary Columns:
['hospital_expire_flag', 'gender_F', 'gender_M', 'age_-65', 'age_+65', 'PAPs', 'PAPd', 'PAPm', 'SvO2 SQI', 'HR_65-89', 'HR_90-99', 'HR_+100', 'ABPs_0-119', 'ABPs_+120', 'ABPd_0-79', 'PO2 (Arterial)_0-74', 'PO2 (Arterial)_75-99', 'PO2 (Arterial)_+100', 'SaO2_0-94', 'SaO2_95-100', 'PCO2 (Arterial)_0-34', 'PCO2 (Arterial)_35-45', 'PCO2 (Arterial)_+45', 'PH (Venous)_0-7.30', 'PH (Venous)_7.31-7.41', 'PH (Venous)_7.41+', 'HCO3 (serum)_0-22', 'HCO3 (serum)_23-29', 'Temperature F_-97', 'Temperature F_97-99', 'Temperature F_+99', 'Creatinine (serum)_-0.74', 'Creatinine (serum)_0.74-1.35', 'Creatinine (serum)_+1.35', 'Total Bilirubin_0.1-1.2', 'Total Bilirubin_+1.2', 'Heart Rhythm_AF (Atrial Fibrillation)', 'Heart Rhythm_SR (Sinus Rhythm)', 'Heart Rhythm_ST (Sinus Tachycardia) ', 'Skin Temp_Cool', 'Skin Temp_Warm']

CNon Binary Columns:
[]

Solo Columns:
[]
```

Could someone please advise me on how to correct this issue?

I don't what I can do in order to solve this problem.

Comment: Strange. I have this error when I use accuracy_score with y_pred being a probability (not a binary variable). However, your use of accuracy_score together with the output from predict() looks correct. Can you give the shape of X_train, y_train, X_test and y_test?

Comment: Sure, @nemo. Here it is: Shape of X_train: (372, 38) Shape of y_train: (372,) Shape of X_test: (160, 38) Shape of y_test: (160,)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use regressor models and not classifier models. The predict() function from the LinearRegression(), RandomForestRegressor() and SVR() will all give float numbers, not binary values, which will induce the reported error ("*ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of binary and continuous targets*") when used with an accuracy metric.

For each regressor model you propose, there is a corresponding classifier model.

The following toy example will work:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)

def fit_and_accuracy(model, X, y):
    clf = model.fit(X, y)
    y_pred = clf.predict(X)
    print(accuracy_score(y, y_pred))

fit_and_accuracy(LogisticRegression(solver='newton-cg'), X, y)
fit_and_accuracy(DecisionTreeClassifier(), X, y)
fit_and_accuracy(SVC(), X, y)
fit_and_accuracy(RandomForestClassifier(), X, y)
fit_and_accuracy(MLPClassifier(), X, y)
```

In your code, you should thus use either LogisticRegression, DecisionTreeCLassifier, SVC, RandomForestClassifier, or MLPClassifier, or any other classifier, but not a regressor.